# Are the two functions different by a constant?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Started from
\begin{align}
\int{\frac{1}{\cos x}dx}&=\int{\frac{\cos x}{1-{{\sin }^{2}}x}dx}\\
&=\tanh^{-1}(\sin x)+C\quad\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\text{ (*)}\\
&=\ln\sqrt{\left|\frac{\sin x+1}{\sin x-1}\right|}+C
\end{align}

(*) can be solved by setting $\tanh Y=\sin x=\frac{e^{2Y}-1}{e^{2Y}+1}$.

On the other side, if Euler formula is used, it will take a substantially different look, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\int{\frac{1}{\cos x}dx}&=\int\frac{2e^{ix}}{e^{2ix}+1}dx\\
&=-2i\tan^{-1}(e^{ix})+C\\
&=\ln\left|\frac{1-ie^{ix}}{1+ie^{ix}}\right|+C
\end{align}

But I could not convert one to the other. Would it be possible that two functions are equivalent
$\left|\frac{1-ie^{ix}}{1+ie^{ix}}\right|\leftrightarrow\sqrt{\left|\frac{\sin x+1}{\sin x-1}\right|}$?

**EDIT:** The motivation is that in general the trigonometric functions can be easier to integrate in exponential form, but the final results can be intimidatingly different from the expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps are the following.
$$
\sqrt{\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}+2i}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}-2i}}=
\sqrt{\frac{e^{2ix}-1+2ie^{ix}}{e^{2ix}-1-2ie^{ix}}}=
\sqrt{\left(\frac{e^{ix}+i}{e^{ix}-i}\right)^2}
$$

Comment: Yes, I missed a simple trick!